# Anyone know about Rhomobile?

Tags: html, ruby, frameworks, rhomobile

I read about http://rhomobile.com/ and I found this is great but I want to ask whether the application built with that would run in Browser or Natively on the device as this requires HTML and Ruby?

Answer (score 2):

The application generated using Rhodes are pure Native application... And there is no need to install Ruby on devices as Rhodes will take core of it..
May be this URl is helpful :
http://itsallaboutruby.blogspot.com/2010/08/rhodes-framework.html

Abhishek

Answer (score 1):

Both, actually.

Your application *is* a web application, but it doesn't run on the internet, it runs on a small webserver that is part of your application inside the phone. It also doesn't run in the browser, but rather in a native browser widget inside your application.

Since the webserver runs on the phone itself, it has access to all the native capabilities of the phone, so you can make HTTP calls to the webserver to capture sound from the microphone, shoot video with the camera, get the GPS location, get multitouch info and so on.

Comment: That's great! Can you guide me please how to get started? I am totally new to Ruby too.