# Rhodes application in mobile web browser

Tags: rhomobile, rhodes

Can I run an application built using rhodes in to a mobile web browser ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definetly Yes. I have created an Web App and sucessfully tested in devices with out having any issues.

This one will gives you better clarification as Pablo metioned link.

http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/device-caps#run-rhodes-application-from-browser

Answer (score 1):

It seems possible for Android and iPhone platforms, but I was not able to test it yet. You can check [this link](http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/device-caps#run-rhodes-application-from-browser) for the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I would say no, you can't. You can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504875/anyone-know-about-rhomobile), it also supports my answer.
However you can start a rhodes application from a browser, see [this link](http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/device-caps#run-rhodes-application-from-browser) from Rhomobile's documentation on device capabilities..

The nice thing about Rhodes is that it can generate native code for the different operating systems you can find in the market. If you just want a web based app, I suggest you use something like [Sencha](http://www.sencha.com/).